# Does Microsoft OneDrive allows a buisness parter to connect with it without Oauth Authentication

Tags: ios, onedrive

We want to integrate our mobile app with OneDrive , but i do not want my user to explicitly login into OneDrive.

The flow which i want is like.

Our app will authenticate the user based on his credentials stored in our organization's LDAP.
Once the user is authorized we want to enable him to his OneDrive account through our application.

Comment: I believe you can connect to One Drive using a protocol with LDAP

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.
OAuth 2.0 is the only public api for authentication, as stated [on the OneDrive API Documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/readme.htm).

You can verify authorization against LDAP first, but the user is going to *have* to log in to authorize access to their OneDrive at some point, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

An open source library is doing the same - checkout --

https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS